# MySQL works in terminal but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysqli, centos

I have migrated my project from AWS to Google Cloud. I had a working application earlier, but now after migrating to GCP, **mysqli_connect** no longer seems to work.
So far, I have installed the following:

1. php-mysql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
2. php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
3. php-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
4. php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
5. php-cli-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
6. mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
7. mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64

I am able to access MySQL using terminal but unable to connect to the remote database (on AWS RDS) using PHP. The RDS Database doesn't have any restriction on IP Connection and is open to the world. I have tried removing PHP, MySQL, MariaDB completely, however, no success. The script to connect to the database is unchanged since migration. Other functions such as **mysqli_fetch_assoc** and **mysqli_query** are not throwing any error. Here is the content of **mysqld_log**:

```
170329 07:20:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
170329 07:31:09 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
170329 07:31:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2017-03-29 07:31:09 0 [Warning] s deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-03-29 07:31:09 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.35) starting as process 32611 ...
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.35 started; log sequence number 1626037
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-03-29 07:31:09 32611 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.35'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: your mysqld_log looks fine. What error does your php script print when you try to connect?

Comment: If you can connect to MySQL via terminal, then the issue cannot really be with MySQL, can it?

Comment: I am confused. @Dimi

Comment: you have PDO installed. Try to use this guide https://phpdelusions.net/pdo and see if it works for you. (or if it prints an error)

Answer (score 0):

You write that you use mysqli_connect, but you have installed php-mysql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (Note: no 'i'). You need the package for mysqli in order for PHP to connect.

Comment: What is the package name for PHP-MySQLi? I was referring to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-mysqli-on-my-server and found that they both are same.

Comment: Oh, then that's not the issue. You could try with other database libraries (mysql_connect or pdo). If they work, then it's a library issue. If they don't work then it's a connection issue. Either the database not being there or your credentials not being correct.